# How can I generate a random number which is, higher or lower than the random number generated before?

Tags: c++, random

/*Instead of increment 1 or decrease 1 the random number in the for loop, I would like the code to generate a random integer higher than the previous random generated if guess is higher and to generate a random integer lower than the previous random generated if the guess is lower./

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int counter = 0;
    unsigned int guess;
    srand(time(NULL));
    unsigned int random_number = (rand() % 100)+ 1;

    std::string higher = "higher";
    std::string lower = "lower";
    std::string value = "";

    cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 100, so the computer can guess it!" << endl;
    cin >> guess;
    cout << random_number << endl;

    while (guess != random_number)
    {
        cout << "Is it a lower or higher value?" << endl;
        cin >> value;
        if (value == higher)
        {
            for(int i = 1; i< 2; i++)
            {
                random_number = random_number + 1;
                cout << random_number << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (value == lower)
        {
            for(int i =1; i < 2; i++)
            {
                random_number = random_number - 1;
                cout << random_number << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "This PC is fabulous" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You used `(rand() % 100)+ 1;` to get a random number in the range you wanted.  Just modify it with the new range you want.

Comment: I did it before, but it will always print the same random number,i think because I can only use srand once.

Comment: Yes, you only use `srand` once.  You change the 100 and 1 in `(rand() % 100)+ 1` to the new range you want and then call that.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call random with your new limits.

To make things easier let us write a function that generates integers between any two limits we specify, say `low_limit` and `low_limit`.

```
int random(int low_limit, int up_limit){
    return rand() % ((up_limit - low_limit) + 1) + low_limit;
}
```

Now generate the first number by calling the function and save the result into a `temp` variable.

```
temp = random (0, 100);
```

Now upon user input you can use `temp` to call `random` like this:

```
   if (value == higher)
       temp = random (temp, 100);
    else if (value == lower)
       temp = random (0, temp);
```

For different random numbers each run you can use `srand` function with a parameter that can give a different seed each time like system time.

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

note: Use the proper headers.

**UPDATE**

Based on your comments, you can use extra two variables say: `minguess` and `maxguess` to narrow your random generation range. check the following piece of code:

```
srand(time(NULL));
int choice, minguess = 0, maxguess = 100, current;
do{
    choice = 0;
    current = random(minguess,maxguess);
    cout << "\n My guess is: " << current << "\n";
    while (choice < 1 || choice > 3){
        cout << "\n Enter you choice: \n";
        cout << " 1- higher. \n";
        cout << " 2- lower. \n";
        cout << " 3- quit. \n\n";
        cin >> choice;
    }
    if (choice == 1)
        minguess = current;
    else if (choice == 2)
        maxguess = current;
} while (choice != 3);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, very helpful! Btw, did you come up yourself with this random function?

Comment: Thank you so much, very helpful! But in a case in which I have guess = 65 for example and I tell the computer to guess it, and in the first loop for example gives me 14, in the second loop 50, in the 3rd loop 67, 4th loop give me 12. How can I handle the case in which the computer  acknowledge the values inserted before, so I can point it in the right direction? For example: being guess = 65, 1st loop gives 14, second loop 50, 3rd loop 67, 4th loop 59, 5th loop 63, 7th loop 65.How can i orient the program in that direction?

Comment: You want the computer to guess a number in your mind between 1 and 100 by narrowing randomly generated numbers?

Comment: @pleka7, If yes, you can use two variables `minguess` and `maxguess`. Initialize them to `0` and `100` respectively. and call `random(minguess,maxguess)` then you change them as needed.

Comment: Thank you @Shadi! Yes, I would like the program to narrow it down, based on the previous generated numbers, for example knowing that the number guessed is less than 60 and more than 40, and not give me numbers like 12 !

Comment: @pleka7         Check the ***Update*** section in the answer.